# Is there a way to determine what caused the last growth operation of my database (MDF file)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, disk-space, dmv, auto-growth

If I don't already have any logging in place, is there any way to use the DMVs or anything else on SQL Server to determine which query / event caused my database's last grow operation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the undocumented function `sys.fn_dblog` filtering by the collumn transaction name like this:

```
SELECT [Transaction Name] 
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL) 
WHERE [Transaction Name] IS NOT NULL;
```

On the query result you should look for **SetFileSize**

[image: Query result]

The line before the **SetFileSize** will show the last event that occured to cause the growth.